# Usando JQuery DataTables com o ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, json, jquery-datatables, filtro

Tenho dúvidas como fazer para usar o DataTables com o MVC 5 e com botão submit retornando um Json conforme o site: [DataTables](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "scripts/post.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "last_name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "start_date" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ]
} );} );
```

1. Usar o MVC e não php
2. Como eu devo colocar a chamada para ActionResult do MVC e retornar um JSON conforme o componente espera.
3. Eu queria colocar campos para filtrar exemplo Nome Endereço e descer para o controlador esse dois campos e la fazer uma chamada para banco retornando resultado que não sei como converter para o Json que o componente espera:

   ```
   {
     "draw": 1,
     "recordsTotal": 57,
     "recordsFiltered": 57,
     "data": [
       {
         "first_name": "Airi",
         "last_name": "Satou",
         "position": "Accountant",
         "office": "Tokyo",
         "start_date": "28th Nov 08",
         "salary": "$162,700"
       },
       {
         "first_name": "Cedric",
         "last_name": "Kelly",
         "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
         "office": "Edinburgh",
         "start_date": "29th Mar 12",
         "salary": "$433,060"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

Comment: Por favor, crie um título que descreva sucintamente o seu problema. As *tags* não devem ser usadas como título.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não muda muito o jeito com que é feito no PHP. Ao descrever o Ajax:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": "scripts/post.php",
    "type": "POST"
},
```

Faça a View escrever o script JS da seguinte forma:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": @Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController"),
    "type": "POST"
},
```

[`@Url.Action` aceita várias formas de ser chamado](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx). Feito isso, declare uma Action no seu Controller da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MinhaAction(FormCollection formCollection) 
{
    // Leia os dados de formCollection aqui (é um dicionário).
    // Retorne um JSON para seu AJAX usando JSON.NET.

    return Json(meusObjetos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

`meusObjetos` podem user um objeto ou uma coleção deles. O JSON.NET sabe serializar os objetos corretamente em JSON.

Para instalar o JSON.NET, utilize o NuGet:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/
>       }

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar, mas se tiver um código de exemplo de como passar filtro para poder ser mas próximo do real.

Comment: Primeiro evolua com o código do exemplo, depois abra outra pergunta mais específica. Creio ser muita coisa pra uma resposta só.